# AWS - Centos7 - /home/.aws/credentials not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have a Centos7 VPS with AWS CLI installed on the `/home` directory.  I've added my credentials into `aws configure` and it's generated the following files:

```
/home/.aws/credentials

/home/.aws/config
```

If I run the following code, it fails:

```
$client = new Aws\Lightsail\LightsailClient([
    'region' => 'eu-west-2',
    'version' => '2016-11-28'
]);
```

The error message is:

```
AccessDeniedException (client): User: arn:aws:sts::523423432423:assumed-role/AmazonLightsailInstanceRole/i-0eb5b2155b08e5185 is not authorized to perform
```

However if I add my credentials like so it works:

```
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('key', 'secret');

$client = new Aws\Lightsail\LightsailClient([
    'region' => 'eu-west-2',
    'version' => '2016-11-28',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
```

Do I need to do something extra in order to get my script to read the `/home/.aws/credentials` file?

Comment: You assigned your ec2 instance an IAM instance profile, which takes precedence over the local credentials file. IAM instance profiles is generally how you should be providing IAM credentials to services on ec2, instead of distributing access keys

Answer (score 1):

```
Do I need to do something extra in order to get my script to read the /home/.aws/credentials file?
```

Yes, you need to put the `.aws/credentials` directory in the home directory of the user running the command.  This will be something like `/home/username` instead meaning that the full path to the credentials will be `/home/username/.aws/credentials`.  It does not matter where you installed the `aws` command to.